# Object error with fetch api request onSubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, fetch-api

Playing with the fetch api at the CodePen link below, attempting to build a user profile card with data pulled from a Github profile when querying the username `onSubmit`. When I extract the fetch block from the `getUserProfile()` function it works fine, but when I call it from the button click I just get `[object Error] {}`. What am I missing?

https://codepen.io/smallreflection/pen/omxxmr

```js
// https://flaviocopes.com/fetch-api/
// https://css-tricks.com/using-fetch
 
let myUserName = document.querySelector('#user-name');
let myUserProfile = document.querySelector('#user-profile-img');
let myCompanyName = document.querySelector('#user-company');
let myUserLink = document.querySelector('#user-link');


var getUserProfile = (e) => {
 console.clear();
 let userId = document.querySelector('#user-name-input').value;
 
 if (userId === '') { e.preventDefault(); }
 
 console.log(userId);

 return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${userId}`)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
    myUserName.innerText = data.name;
    myUserProfile.style.backgroundImage = `url(${data.avatar_url})`;
    myCompanyName.innerText = data.company;
    myUserLink.setAttribute('href', `${data.html_url}`);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
} // getUserProfile
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

:root {
 --border-radius: 7px;
 --color-gray-x-light: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
 --color-gray-light: hsl(0, 0%, 65%);
 --color-orange: hsl(20,95%,65%);
}

#user-wrapper {
 max-width:500px;
}

body { 
 font-family: arial;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 background-color:var(--color-gray-x-light);
 min-height:100vh;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { letter-spacing:-.05rem; }

#input-container {
 border-radius: var(--border-radius);
 display:flex;
 background-color:#fff;
 padding: 1rem 1.2rem;
 box-shadow:0 5px 15px hsla(0,0,0,.2);
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:1rem;
}

form > input { 
 border:solid 1px var(--color-gray-light);
 font-size:1rem;
 height:38px;
 padding:5px 10px;
 background-color: var(--color-gray-x-light); 
 border-radius:var(--border-radius);
 flex-grow:1;
}

form > input::placeholder {
 color:var(--color-gray-light);
}

form > button {
 border:0;
 color: #fff;
 background-color:var(--color-orange);
 border-radius:var(--border-radius);
 height:38px;
 font-size:1rem;
 padding:5px 10px;
 margin:0 0 0 .75rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight:bold;
}

#user-profile {
 float:left;
 vertical-align:top;
 background-color:#fff;
 box-shadow:0 5px 15px hsla(0,0,0,.2);
 padding:1rem 1.2rem;
 border-radius:var(--border-radius);
 width:100%;
}

#user-profile-img {
 float:left;
 width:85px;
 height:85px;
 background: hsl(200, 5%, 92%);
 border-radius:50%;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:1rem;
 background-size:cover;
}

a {
 color: hsl(20,95%,65%);
 text-decoration:none;
}


#user-info {
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:200px;
}

#user-info > h1 {
 font-size:24px;
 margin:12px 0 3px 0;
}

#user-company {
 font-size:15px;
 font-style: italic;
 color: hsl(200, 5%, 75%);
}
```

```html
<div id="user-wrapper">

 <div id="input-container">
  <form id="get-username">
   <input placeholder="Enter Github user ID" id="user-name-input" name="user-name-input">
   <button onClick="getUserProfile()">Get User</button>
  </form>
 </div>

 <div id="user-profile">
  <div id="user-profile-img"></div>
  <div id="user-info">
   <h1 id="user-name">My User</h1>
   <span id="user-company">Company Name</span><br/>
   <a href="#" id="user-link" target="_blank">View profile</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing the `event` Object.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is because `e` is not defined you need to explicitly pass in the `event` to get `getUserProfile` when passing it to `onClick`

`<button onClick="getUserProfile(event)">Get User</button>`

Updated code `getUserProfile`

```
let getUserProfile = (e) => {
    console.clear();
    let userId = document.querySelector('#user-name-input').value;
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${userId}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            myUserName.innerText = data.name;
            myUserProfile.style.backgroundImage = `url(${data.avatar_url})`;
            myCompanyName.innerText = data.company;
            myUserLink.setAttribute('href', `${data.html_url}`);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: This is no longer the recommended way to stop the navigation. Instead, use the function itself should use `event.preventDefault()` and should be attached to the button using `document.addEventListener`. In any case, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You shouldn't camelCase onclick, though.

Comment: @PHPglue camelCase for `onClick` will probably keep working for many years, since it used to be the standard. If you're going to change it, I would say you shouldn't use `onclick` at all. That's what `addEventListener` is for.

Comment: `element.addEventListener('click', listenerFunc)` and `element.onclick = listenerFunc` do differ. With the first kind you will have to `element.removeEventListener('click', listenerFunc)` if you are trying to simply overwrite the Event. Of course, `addEventListner` allows you to attach multiple events, without overwriting the Events. Since `element.onclick = listenerFunc` will overwrite you can store a reference like `var preClicked = element.onclick; element.onclick = function(){ preClicked(); // now add your new event }`. I prefer the overwritable kind.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried targeting the event in my JS before but was missing passing the event in the HTML. :)